# How to update XML file using JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, xml, jsp

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Names>
 <Person>George</Person>
 <Person>Mary</Person>
 <Person>John</Person>
</Names>
```

I am working on a project in JSP. Right now, my program successfully extracts contents from an XML file and outputs them into a div. I also have some textboxes that read user input. I'm trying to update the contents of my XML file (*using Client Side*) to what the user input into the textbox, and then call the Names() method to output the contents of the updated file into the div (replacing the old contents). However, my XML file isn't updating, and I am unsure on how to go about doing this. Here is my code:

```
function getXML(){
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }

         else{
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
           xmlhttp.open("GET","Names.xml",false);
           xmlhttp.send();
           return(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }

         function loadXMLDoc(dname) {


                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }

                  else {
                      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }

                   xmlDoc.async = false;
                     xmlDoc.load(dname);
                    xmlDoc.save("Names.xml");
                    return (xmlDoc);
             }


             function insertNames(){


            var name1 = document.getElementById('NameOne').value;
            var name2 = document.getElementById('NameTwo').value;
            var name3= document.getElementById('NameThree').value;

           if(name1 != null || name2 != null || name3 != null){


           xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("Names.xml");

          var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person")[0].childNodes[0];
          x.nodeValue = weekdayHours;
          var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person")[0].childNodes[1];
          y.nodeValue = saturdayHours;
          var z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person")[0].childNodes[2];
          z.nodeValue = sundayHours;
             xmlDoc.save("Names.xml");
              Names(); 
    }
  }
  function Names() {
      var xml = getXML();
      var txt = "";
      $(xml).find("Person").each(function () {
        txt += "<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
      });
      $("body").append(txt);
    }

    Names();
```

Is this possible to do? If so, what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Your JavaScript contains functions that don't appear to be getting called (e.g. loadXMLDoc and insertNames).

**You cannot update the contents of a file using client side JavaScript.**

- you can use client side JavaScript to change the content displayed in
  the browser

  *AND / OR*
- you can use client side JavaScript to pass user input to a server
  side JSP that could then produce different XML as a result.

Perhaps you could explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish then we could be more helpful?

Comment: Mark, first of all, thanks for your response. I didn't post it, but `insertNames()` is the function called when a user clicks the update button. `loadXMLDoc()` is being called within the `if` statement in the `insertNames()` method. I have an XML file already. The `Names()` function just reads the contents and outputs to a div. I also have 3 textboxes and an update button. I want to read the text that the user input into the textboxes. Then, update my XML files. As you can see, the last line of my `insertNames()` function calls `Names()`. This is so that I can output the updated XML results.

Comment: Your JavaScript is a bit mixed up.  Some of it looks like it comes from a load function (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp) but there isn't a "save" function like this in JavaScript.

Comment: I have a save method. But if I remove it, how will I get the XML file to update?

Comment: You cannot update files using client side JavaScript.  You can update what is displayed in the browser AND/OR pass data back to the server side.

Comment: Is it possible to do this through java, while reading user input from the text box?

Comment: Yes, server side Java/JSP could modify a server side XML file (or at least store these values somewhere that they could be used to produce an XML output)

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! This is very helpful, I appreciate your help.